# Create Java with Ant Application from VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ant, vscode-extensions

I want to create  a new "Java with Ant" Application from VSCode just like is done in Apache Netbeans. I installed the required extensions for running Java in VSCode and even the "Apache netbeans language server Extension" but I'm unable to find the option "Java with Ant" when creating a new Java project from VSCode. →
Image from NetBeans:
[Java with ant from NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIr9Q.png)

Comment: There's no such option in VS Code. You may search specific tutorial online about developing Ant application in VS Code .

Comment: Now java extension only supports maven and gradle. May i know the reason you want this feature that java extension support ant? Does work or study need it?

Comment: College. The professor pointed out that we needed to create a "Java with ant" project from netbeans. But I don't like netbeans. My workaround is creating the project in netbeans and opening in VSCode or IntelliJ.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT there a lot of older/legacy enterprise apps built using ant - some quite complex and large.  i too am looking for a good well supported solution for this in vscode and came across this post.   i'd settle for a converter to maven (as gradle only supports more recent versions of java).  are you aware of any such thing?